# Error posting to URL 400 Bad Request when I try deploy to app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, maven-compiler-plugin, appengine-maven-plugin

A few months ago my application was deploying perfectly to appengine but I tried to deploy it today but I got these errors in the log:

```
Beginning interaction for module default...
May 07, 2016 3:46:08 AM com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection send1
WARNING: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/getresourcelimits?app_id=%24%7Bapp.id%7D&version=1&
400 Bad Request
Client Error (400)The request is invalid for an unspecified reason.
This is try #0
May 07, 2016 3:46:08 AM com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection send1
WARNING: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/getresourcelimits?app_id=%24%7Bapp.id%7D&version=1&
400 Bad Request
Client Error (400)The request is invalid for an unspecified reason.
This is try #1
May 07, 2016 3:46:08 AM com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection send1
WARNING: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/getresourcelimits?app_id=%24%7Bapp.id%7D&version=1&
400 Bad Request
Client Error (400)The request is invalid for an unspecified reason.
This is try #2
May 07, 2016 3:46:09 AM com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection send1
WARNING: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/getresourcelimits?app_id=%24%7Bapp.id%7D&version=1&
400 Bad Request
Client Error (400)The request is invalid for an unspecified reason.
This is try #3

com.google.appengine.tools.admin.HttpIoException: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/getresourcelimits?app_id=%24%7Bapp.id%7D&version=1&
400 Bad Request
Client Error (400)The request is invalid for an unspecified reason.

Unable to update app: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/getresourcelimits?app_id=%24%7Bapp.id%7D&version=1&
400 Bad Request
Client Error (400)The request is invalid for an unspecified reason.

Please see the logs [/var/folders/dg/1d63fk7n5r9c05hnbn7z2nx80000gp/T/appcfg6594780979158835679.log] for further information.
```

I think the problem comes from the `app_id` specified in the url; `https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/getresourcelimits?app_id=%24%7Bapp.id%7D&version=1&`

The `app_id` in that url is `%24%7Bapp.id%7D` but it is actually `ornate-woodland-130423`

Here is my appengine_web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <application>${app.id}</application>
    <version>${app.version}</version>
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>

    <system-properties>
        <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
    </system-properties>
</appengine-web-app>
```

Extract from my pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <app.id>ornate-woodland-130423</app.id>
    <app.version>1</app.version>
    <appengine.version>1.9.37</appengine.version>
    <gcloud.plugin.version>2.0.9.89.v20151202</gcloud.plugin.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.showDeprecation>true</maven.compiler.showDeprecation>
</properties>
```

Is there anyway I can fix this?

Comment: Decoded url looks like this: `https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/getresourcelimits?app_id=${app.id}&version=1&`. Seems like variable for app.id is not set, please check or post your pom.xml and appengine-web.xml

Comment: This was great help. It worked after I explicitly put the app_id in the `appengine_web.xml` instead of having `${app.id}`. It used to work before all along but for some reason now it is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this wasn't working was because the `app.id` needs to be specified explicitly in `appengine_web.xml`. Hence why in the URL it said the `app.id` was `%24%7Bapp.id%7D`. Which is actually ${app.id} as someone above pointed out.

So instead of setting it implicitly like this;

```
<application>${app.id}</application>
```

I changed it to this and it worked

```
<application>ornate-woodland-130423</application>
```